# Change the size of unlock pattern grid

Tags: lock-screens, 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-4

On some of the screenshots I've seen the pattern unlock use a much larger grid instead of the default 3x3.

I can't find any way to change the size of the grid in the settings.

Can I somehow change the grid size on the stock unlocker or is that some custom stuff? The screens look like they're from a stock ROM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bigger pattern lock is a Cyanogenmod feature that was introduced in 10.1 late last year.  I do not believe it is currently included in stock android.

https://plus.google.com/+CyanogenMod/posts/eHpv1QCoRuc